# What are the various WPF binding modes?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I do not understand the various data binding modes in WPF, such as:

- One-Way
- Two-Way
- One-Time
- etc...

What does each of these modes mean?

When should they be used?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

- `OneWay`: Use this when you want the bound property to update the user interface.
- `TwoWay`: This has the same behavior as `OneWay` and `OneWayToSource` combined. The bound property will update the user interface, and changes in the user interface will update the bound property (You would use this with a `TextBox` or a `Checkbox`, for example.)
- `OneTime`: This has the same behavior as `OneWay`, except it will only update the user interface one time. This should be your default choice for binding (for various reasons I won't elaborate on here). You should only use other types of bindings if you actually need the extra functionality.
- `OneWayToSource`: This is the opposite of `OneWay` -- user interface value changes update the bound property.

If you don't specify anything, then the behavior will depend on the control that you are using.

For more info, see `BindingMode` enum on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode).

Comment: Thanks. it is helpful...
But plz specify the TwoWay example... i want to know how its reflect the code-behind.

Comment: @DATT: what do you mean by "specify"?  Basically, if you set Mode=TwoWay in the XAML, when you change the GUI value, it will automatically update the C# property.  But your property in code-behind needs to be implemented in a class (like a ViewModel) that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  When the code-behind changes the value of the property via set, you need to call PropertyChanged so that the GUI is notified of the value change, and it will update itself automatically.

Comment: If you don't specify anything, then the behavior will depend on the PROPERTY that you are using.

Answer (score 49):

A binding consists of two entities:

1. **The Source (Typically the ViewModel in MVVM scenarios)**
2. **The Target (The UI control)**

The target has to be a `DependencyObject` (for binding to work) and the source can be either a `DependencyObject` or it should have some mechanism to imitate the WPF Binding system about it being changed (Implemeting `INotifyPropetyChnaged` interface).

---

MVVM recommends the ViewModel project to be free from any View related references and hence it is recommended to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to make the Source object being heard by WPF binding.
Binding happens between a property of **Source** and a property of **Target** (has to be a `DependencyProperty`).
e.g. The `TextProperty`of the `TextBox` class is DataBound to (say) `UserName` property of the view model.
WPF binding offers four types of Binding. Remember, Binding runs on UI thread unless otherwise you specify it to run otherwise.

1. **OneWay**: The *target property* will listen to the source property being changed and will update itself. If you programmatically change the ViewwModel's `UserName` property, it will reflect in the text box. This is of intermediate cost as the binding system watches only **Source** for changes.
2. **TwoWay**: The target property will listen to the source property being changed and will update itself. AND The source property will listen to the target property being changed and will update itself. Both the `TextProperty` and the `UserName` property will remain in sync and will update each other if one changes. This is most costly as the binding system has to watch both sides for change.
3. **OneWayToSource**: The Source property will change if the target property is changed. If the user changes the `TextProperty`, the `UserName` property will take up the changed value. This again is of intermediate cost as the binding system watches only **Target** for changes.
4. **OneTime**: This happens only once during the lifetime of Binding, the **Target** property will be updated with the **Source** property when the Binding happens. This is least costly and is advisable for scenarios where you have static data to be shown e.g. `Label`, `TextBlock` etc.

If you don't mention anything, every **target** property has a default binding mode associated with itself. E.g. the `TextProperty` of a `TextBox` has default binding mode as `TwoWay`. For the `TextProperty` of a `TextBlock` it is one way.

It is advisable that you choose the right mode as it can help you reduce the application latency especially in cases where you have large number of controls in your UI.

For more on MVVM [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/753332/XPence-A-WPF-metro-style-smart-client-expense-trac) is an article written by me.