# WPF Datagrid does not get updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have define a datagrid as follow:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="s" MaxHeight="300"
           ItemsSource="{Binding MsgCollection, IsAsync=False, Mode=OneTime}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BankId"
                            Header="Bank Nr."
                            Binding="{Binding BankId}"
                            DisplayIndex="0" />

        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MessageB"
                            Header="Message B"
                            Binding="{Binding MessageB}"
                            DisplayIndex="1" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

the viewModel Code looks like this:

```
 public class AwesomeDataViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
   ...
   public ObservableCollection<Bank> MsgCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Msgs;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Msgs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MsgCollection");
        }
    }

 AwesomeRandomMethode(){
    ...
    // bankCollection contains 200 items
     MsgCollection = new ObservableCollection<Bank>(bankCollection); 
    OnPropertyChanged("MsgCollection");
 }
}
```

The `AwesomeRandomMethode()` is called later in the program to add items into the dataGrid.
I notify the change by calling `OnPropertyChanged`but nothing happens.

I know the`OnPropertyChanged` works, because i have a button that make use of it and it get notified.

However if I toggle the tab, suddenly the datagrid get updated!

Im looking for a solution that does not violate MVVM principles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is your binding it should be a two way binding on the source items. A default binding is a TwoWay so just don't declare it explicitly.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="s" MaxHeight="300" ItemsSource="{Binding MsgCollection}">
</DataGrid>
```

You should also just have your ObservableCollection declared already and Add or Remove Items. This way everything will up date automatically.

Comment: God dammit, I spent several hours to solve this stupid "Mode=TwoWay" thx,

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ItemSource="{Binding MsgCollection, IsAsync=False, Mode=OneTime}"
```

for

```
ItemSource="{Binding MsgCollection, IsAsync=False, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

WPF binding modes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305234/5147720