# WPF switching column visibility in DataGrid triggers unwanted event

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a weird issue where changing data grid column visibility with a press of a button, it triggers a "Checked" event tied to a checkbox in that data grid column.

So here's my setup:

- I have a label `lblUpdateMode` with a text either "single row" or "every row";
- A datagrid with 10 columns, where initially 5 columns are visible and 5 are hidden;
- Pressing a button `btnChangeView` flips visibility of each column;
- In one of the data grid columns I have a CheckBoxColumn, with Checked/Unchecked events. If label `text = "every row"` pressing on a single checkbox updates every row.

However, if `label = "every row"` and I press on `btnChangeView`, it also triggers Checked event and updates checkboxes in every row.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Here's the code to the Checked event - nothing fancy or strange:

```
private void UpdateDataGridCheckBox(string colname, bool v)
{
    if (lblUpdateMode.Content.ToString() == "Every Row")
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in DataAccess.Instance.sourceFiles.Rows)
        {
            dr[colname] = v;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML for this column:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridFiles" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" Visibility="Collapsed"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataAccess.Instance.sourceFiles, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--Import-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Import" Width="60" CanUserReorder="True" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBoxImport" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=Import, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  Checked="checkBoxImport_Checked"
                                  Unchecked="checkBoxImport_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, post your xaml. and the btnChangeView code behind

Comment: Likely a problem with the check box trigger association in your `XAML`. Yeah please post the `XAML` and the button code behind.

Comment: I've added XAML for the one of the checkbox. Code behind for the button is very simple: grid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            grid.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            grid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            grid.Columns[3].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

Comment: @Sach, is this something you can assist me with? Thanks.

Comment: What is the `Import` property in your code behind? And where do you change the value of that in the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `XAML`, you bind the `IsChecked` property of your `CheckBox` to a property called `Import`.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBoxImport" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=Import, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Checked="checkBoxImport_Checked"
          Unchecked="checkBoxImport_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
```

However, the binding `Mode` is set to `TwoWay`, which means,

- If there's a change of value in the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` in your `XAML`, that change will be reflected in your `Import` property in your code,

and,

- If there's a change of value in the `Import` property in your code, that change will be reflected in the actual `CheckBox` in your `XAML`.

In other words, if the user checks the check box, `Import` value will be set to `true`. If user unchecks the check box, `Import` will be `false`. Conversely, if you change the value of `Import` to `false` at any point in your code, your GUI check box will be unchecked. If `Import` is set to `true` in code, GUI check box will be checked.

I'm assuming that in the `Click` even of the `btnChangeView` (which you haven't shown in your post), you change the value of `Import`.

So, instead of `Mode=TwoWay`, assuming that you want to do something when the user checks/unchecks the `CheckBox`, I think you want to set `Mode=OneWayToSource`.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305179/what-are-the-various-wpf-binding-modes) for a detailed explanation of binding modes in WPF.