# Why Data Binding without get, set is not working in WPf?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i'm beginner to C# and WPF and I had a question while studying.
Data Binding with get, set is work well like below.

```
 public partial class Some: Window
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "NAME3";

        public Some()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
```

But, Data Binding without get,set dosen't work at all.

```
 public partial class Some: Window
    {
        public string Name = "NAME3";

        public Some()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
```

What is difference between them?
Thank you

Comment: You are not only changing get-set behaviour, in the 2nd code snippet you have a field and not anymore a propery.

Comment: @KargWare I understand! "you have a field and not anymore a propery. " It means Data Binding is possible with 'property' but not with 'field', right?

Comment: Data Binding in WPF works with public properties only. You may want to read [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0).

Answer (score -2):

Check the answer on [SO - What are the various WPF binding modes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305234/10655742).

There are the different Binding-Modes listed.

When you want to go without the `set` may `one-way` is the solution. So only binding from model to view will happen. But that should be only for constant or readonly elemenets on the view.