# Binding width of main window element to child elements doesn't appear to work in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

In the following code, I create a `ComboBox` of width 120. I then bind the width of the enclosing `StackPanel` to the width of this `ComboBox`. Finally, I bind the `Width` property of the main widow to the width of the `StackPanel`.

```xml
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="ExampleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="110" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=stackPanel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=comboBox}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90">
      <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
      <CheckBox Content="First Item"/>
      <CheckBox Content="Second Item"/>
      <CheckBox Content="Third Item"/>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Unfortunately, my window looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and why is the main window width not snapping to the `ComboBox` width as I intend?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the window height and width to the stack panel. You can use a window's [`SizeToContent` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.sizetocontent?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Mode=TwoWay` `Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=stackPanel, Mode=TwoWay}"`

To why `Mode=TwoWay` check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305234

Or use `SizeToContent="Width"` on window, like Lukasz Szczygielek told.